# How to strip specific punctuation from the end of strings in a list and make all words lower case

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and need certain punctuation stripped off the end of each string within the list. The list is like:

```
list = ['Twas', 'brillig,', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'Did', 'gyre',
        'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe:']  #the list is a lot longer
```

I need to strip off all punctuation that includes `'"-,.:;!?` only from the end of each string and make all words lower case.

Io I need `'Twas'` to become `'twas'` and I need `'wabe:'` to become `'wabe'`, etc... other words in the list that i did not include here contain the other punctuation at the end.

I tried using `.rstrip()` and `.lower()` case but I did not know how to use a for or while loop to go through each string in the list and do this. If there is another way that does not need to use `.rstrip` or `.lower` I am open to them.

I am a beginner with using python so the very basic answer would help me and if you could explain exactly what you do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, your question is not about string operations, it's about Python's control constructs such as loops and list comprehensions, isn't it? If so, have you checked out the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)?

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> [el.lower().rstrip('\'\"-,.:;!?') for el in list]
['twas', 'brillig', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'did', 'gyre', 'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe']
```

This is a list comprehension, which is a one line way of writing a for loop which produces a list. It iterates through the list item by item, setting each element to lowercase, and then stripping trailing characters '"-,.:;!?

Comment: I have checked out the tutorial and it did not really help.
I hadn't really tried anything as I did not know how to put it all together. I got given a url that had a poem in it and out teacher gave us a function to put the poem into a list with each string being a word. we then had to make a function that made all words lower case and took the punctuation off the end. I knew i had to use .rstrip and .lower and use a loop but i just couldnt put it all together.
It now works so thank you!!

Comment: @Keely Aranyos - Hey! Glad it works now, and welcome to SO! Please consider 'accepting/upvoting' this answer (if you found it helpful). 
You can do this by clicking on the 'tick' and/or the 'up arrow' to the left. Upvoting is encouraged for helpful posts on SO :)